# Enforce one argument per line in RuboCop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Using RuboCop, I want to disallow method argument formatting that looks like this:

```
some_method(arg_1,
  arg_2)
```

And allow formatting that looks like this:

```
some_method(
  arg_1,
  arg_2
)
```

I also want to allow formatting that looks like this:

```
some_method(arg_1, arg_2)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is the rule you are looking for:

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.45.0/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FirstMethodArgumentLineBreak

to enable it just write this in your rubocop.yml file:

```yaml
Style/FirstMethodArgumentLineBreak:
  Enabled: True
```